# Low power RF amplification

Tags: amplifier, rf, low-power, high-frequency

I am a noob in this.

I would like to amplify a 3MHz modulated sine wave coming from a frequency generator. That is 5Vpp 50ohm ie 0.5W. Or it can be 10Vpp and High Z.

I would like to achieve 2-10W output. Preferably adjustable but fixed 3/4/n/8W would be OK too.

Because I have been obsessed in the last month to find out the answer for above, please help me what are the properties and or maybe the exact name ;) of the device I am looking for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You were well on your way (I'll ignore sentence 3 where you specify power but not load impedance) until sentence 4 where this turns into a shopping question.

Comment: yep, Shopping questions are explicitly off-topic here :) Hint: It's often very easy to re-word a shopping question to a "what are the properties I'd look for in a device?"-question. And that question, then, would both be non-off-topic (not saying it's a great question) and be helpful for potential future readers.

Comment: so will I be beheaded now? :) Whats wrong with shopping questions? OK so what / how do I ask to eventually achieve my goal? I can't find anything which does exactly what I need - believe me I digged up ebay.

Comment: no, we got rid of the beheading rule by the 1. of January this year. Most of us still resent that (**grin**); however, if you don't change your question (see my recommendation above), your question will be closed. Because, what's wrong with it, is that it **is** a shopping/product recommendation question on a site that specifically forbids those.

Comment: BTW: \$5V_{pp}\$ @ \$50\Omega\$ is not 0.5W

Comment: Step back and define your problem in functional and analytical terms defining what SNR you need for this signal and why level is important. Perhaps the receiver can be improved.  Otherwise there is also the controversial Jan 20 Trump card defective rule in effect. (pun). In truth professional EE designers do make/buy "shopping questions" every day, but this encourages too many lame questions from some participants, so thus the rule here.  ... oh and it's 0.5W pp so divide by 2.8 (2rt.(2) to get RMS power. Don't mind @Curd he's just being a friendly nitpicker, and who cares about "real power"

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need voltage gain, but only power gain, there is probably a power opamp that will work for you.  (Search under opamps at Digikey... (a nice search engine.)

Comment: an OpAmp with 10W @ 3MHz? Please show me!

Comment: how do you know that OP doesn't need voltage gain?

Comment: @Curd, well you can search digikey too.   I don't really like them but you might find an APEX part that will do 10 Watts.

Comment: Assuming he needs no voltage amplification is not justified. So gain bandwidth product must be **well** above 3MHz to amplify the 3MHz signal. I didn't find any of those APEX power OpAmps that are nearly approriate (Not to mention the price).

Comment: @Curd, Geesh Crud, I don't know what he wants... are you looking for a power opamp?  Here's one I found on DK... I didn't look at the specs very carefully.  http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1206fb.pdf  (Apex stuff is way over priced., IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PA (Power Amplifier) for the 80m amateur radio band (ca. 3.5MHz).

Google: 80m PA